# Can this be CM related noise?

Tags: noise, common-mode

In a single ended data acquisition system a DAQ board is sampling channels in a multiplexed way. The DAQ is single ended as well as the input signals.
When I use two analog transducers coupled to two channels where ch0 is accelerometer and ch1 is an ultrasonic proximity transducer; in this case I see noise in ch0.

And this noise shifts with the sampling rate. And if I remove the ch1 (ultrasonic sensor), then the noise disappears from ch0.

Obviously ch1 (ultrasonic sensor) is causing aliased noise in ch0. But can this be a common mode noise? What could be happening? (At the moment I'm not able to provide more quantitative data.)

**EDIT UPDATE:**

Noise appears at ch0 even if I only connect the ground of ch1.

I could now draw the complete system:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ7Vqf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

The ultrasonic sensor needs HIGH CURRENTS during transmit. Since the measurement errors show up even with Just The Ground connected, this suggests some power_rail filtering will improve/lower the transient noise floor. That filter needs a capacitor and an inductor.

You need a large capacitor, located within 1mm (that is, very very close) to the GND and VDD pins of the ultrasonic sensor. The purpose is to locally provide the high transient charge demands.

You need a "LOCAL BATTERY" for the ultrasonic sensor; that requires a shunt capacitor and a series impedance. Because of high transmit energy, I'd use 100uF across GND/VDD. And for the series impedance, I'd use 1uH or 10uH.

The capacitor and inductor, together, form a voltage_divider.

Here is the "LOCAL BATTERY" in a circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxHAXM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: But at the end of the day can we call this  type common mode?

Comment: LOCAL BATTERY ? I can use smps only.

Comment: I found out both the transducer ground(through another PC's USB port) and DAQ ground were earth grounded as well.

Comment: Would a 1000uF with 1uH suffice as well? It is hard to locate 1mm.

Comment: Try 1000 uF and 1uH. I agree 1mm is hard to locate the soldering that close; I want you to solder as close as possible. Good luck with all this.

Comment: And here in my edit I draw the complete big picture how things are wired: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Vqf.png

Comment: @floppy380 It's not a real battery, but you can think of it as one. Moreover to what analogsystemsrf said, you need low ESR in your capacitor, not just capacitance.

Comment: @winny How about disconnecting these two mains earth connection? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Vqf.png Would that be a solution as well?

Comment: @floppy380 Separate issue. Start with very strong decoupling as described above.

Comment: @winny The thing is I want to understand how does that current loop from usonic ground to the same usonic ground. I though the earth is causing that loop.

Comment: @floppy380 It’s possible but difficult to tell without full schematic and layout. Whatever the noise issue is, the usual suspects in order are: poor layout, insufficient decoupling and ground loops.

Comment: thank you, winny. I updated the schematic with your recommendation. Any more thoughts on this?

Comment: Better, but 100 uF sounds electrolytic to me. Think 100 nF ceramic first.

Comment: Thanks for being pedantic. Could you also explain these points 1)Why do we need low ESR cap? 2)What is the purpose of the inductor? 3)Why does capacitor type matter in this scnario(ceramic vs electrolytic)?

Comment: why the inductor? filters need a **SERIES** element and a **SHUNT** element. The inductor provides a well-defined and large (at high frequency)SERIES  impedance, thus boosting the effect of the SHUNT (the large electrolytic).

Comment: @floppy380 You need to write @ and username, or the person in question won't be notified. I would suggest you to set up a simulation and test the effect of L, C and ESR. It would greatly improve your understanding and help you in your future EE career.

Answer (score 0):

Quite likely is that the noise you see is what we call cross talk and this can be quite a significant factor when multiplexing multiple analogue signals if, the settling time after diverting from one signal source to the next is inadequate. Try solving this first and forget about the prospect of aliasing until cross talk is ruled out.

If I’m correct then it also has little to do with the DAQ and signals being single ended.

Following an update from the OP, it’s a little clearer that the problem is current pulses/noise taken by the ultrasonic sensor creating a noise on the 0 volts and that noise is cross talking to the other sensor.

Comment: Some update now: I used an isolation module across the ch1 and the DAQ input now(I mean I isolated the usonic sensor output and then coupled to the DAQ)the issue is solved. But still dont know the rootcause. If it is cross-talk would a buffer solve the issue? I heard once cross talk is related to high output impedance.

Comment: Another observation is that if I connect only the ground of the usonic sensor to DAQ ground I still was seeing nosie at ch0. Im adding this now it might help you to picture it better. I just observed these.

Comment: Well it could be current taken by the usonic probe creating noise voltage.

Comment: Just a final update in my edit: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7Vqf.png I normally hate to edit questions but I was not able to draw when I asked the question in hurry.

Comment: Yes, it’s probably the usonic current noise taken through the wiring creating a noise voltage at the DAQ 0 volts reference relative to the voltage seen at the 0 volts connection of the sensor that is being interfered with. Try adding a local decoupling capacitor across the supply rails of the usonic device.

Comment: Thanks btw Im extremely curious how that current loops from sensor ground back to sensor ground. Regarding my diagram the current flows from ground to ground. If it was 50Hz ground loop I would blame Faraday’s law. But in this case what is really causing that current? Should I open another question?

Comment: There’s not enough info to make a solid and precise judgement. However, noise can be very much higher than 50 Hz and propagate in many ways.

Comment: Yes I have been googling about this couldnt find a model that satisfies my reasoning.